# MySQL Java Connector UTF8 Encoding Issue

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to retrieve strings that have been stored as UTF-8 in a MySQL database in Java.

Retrieving them in Python or via the command line produces the correct encoding and all special characters show up the way they are supposed to. However, after retrieving them in Java, most special characters get mangled.

The result looks like this:
RT @okay_password: à¸—à¸µà¹ˆà¹€à¸£à¸²à¹€à¸ˆà¹‡à¸šà¹€à¸£à¸²à¹€à¸ªà¸µà¸¢à¹ƒà¸ˆà¸à¹‡à¹‚à¸—à¸©à¹€à¸‚à¸²à¹„à¸¡à¹ˆà¹„à¸”à¹‰à¸­à¸µà¸à¸™à¸±à¹ˆà¸™à¹à¸«à¸¥à¸° à¸à¹‡à¹€à¸«à¹‡à¸™à¸­à¸¢à¸¹à¹ˆà¸§à¹ˆà¸²à¹€à¸‚à¸²à¹„à¸¡à¹ˆà¹„à¸”à¹‰à¹à¸„à¸£à¹Œà¹€à¸£à¸² à¹à¸•à¹ˆà¹€à¸£à¸²à¸¢à¸±à¸‡à¹€à¸¥à¸·à¸­à¸à¸ˆà¸°à¸­à¸¢à¸¹à¹ˆà¸•à¸£à¸‡à¸™à¸±à¹‰à¸™à¹€à¸­à¸‡ http://t.co/uIâ€¦

or in bytes (from resultSet.getBytes):
52 54 20 40 6F 6B 61 79 5F 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 3A 20 C3 A0 C2 B8 E2 80 94 C3 A0 C2 B8 C2 B5 C3 A0 C2 B9 CB ...

Whereas the correct result should be:
RT @okay_password: ที่เราเจ็บเราเสียใจก็โทษเขาไม่ได้อีกนั่นแหละ ก็เห็นอยู่ว่าเขาไม่ได้แคร์เรา แต่เรายังเลือกจะอยู่ตรงนั้นเอง http://t.co/uI…

(retrieved from the same MySQL table via command line)

or in bytes:
52 54 20 40 6F 6B 61 79 5F 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72 64 3A 20 E0 B8 97 E0 B8 B5 E0 B9 88 E0 B9 80 E0 B8 A3 E0 B8 B2 ...

Note how the first 19 bytes that correspond to western characters match and then it diverges.

Also, the actual output is 2103 bytes long, as opposed to 1047 as it should be.

I've set useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8 and -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 as recommended by some other post but it does not seem to have any effect.

I've also tried decoding the string with every encoding supported by Java but was not able to decode any substring of the mangled part correctly.

I'm at my wits end; what am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

The table was created as 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tweet` ( ... )DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

MySQL shows:

show variables like 'char%';

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

Does this look like an issue?

Edit2:

Tried the ALTER commands. Now the char sets looks like this but the bytes still come out the same way:

```
        mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

8 rows in set (0.10 sec)

Meanwhile I realized, I can reproduce the issue in Python. If i run the query via the regular mysql connector, like this:

```
    import MySQLdb
...
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=MySQL_host , user=MySQL_user, passwd=MySQL_pass, db=MySQL_db__)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""select * from tweet where user_id = '426586170' and time = '2014-03-21+15:10:30';""")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
print data[0][3]
```

the result shows up fine. On the other hand, if I use Oracle's connector like this:

```
import mysql.connector
...
            cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = ("SELECT * from tweet WHERE user_id = '426586170' and time = '2014-03-21+15:10:30'")

cursor.execute(query)

for (tweet_id, user_id, time, text) in cursor:
    print text
```

I get the garbled output again:  RT @okay_password: à¸—à¸µà¹ˆà¹€à¸£à¸²à¹€à¸ˆà¹‡à¸šà¹€à¸£à¸² ...

Can anyone make sense of this?

Comment: What character set and collation is the database table encoded in? It's possible that you've stored UTF-8 characters into a Latin-1 table.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add

```
useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;
```

to your MySQL JDBC connector URL. e.g.:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://dbserver/db?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8"
```

EDIT: I misread the server variables you pasted. Your database charset is still latin1. Try

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: I already tried that. My code looks like this right now

connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/"
+ database + "?"
+ "useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8&" + "user="
+ user + "&password=" + password);

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @MuratOzgul I missed the database charset you pasted. Just updated my answer.